# Move SharePoint list items into folders that exists in the same list programmatically?

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Respected members of StackOverflow, kindly help me with your kind suggestions to solve the issue.

I have +20,000 items in a SharePoint list that i want to move into the folders that also exists in the same list. I would like to move them according to their created date.

For example: Items created on 07-07-2013 should be moved to Folder 2013 --> July
Items created on 12-10-2013 should be moved to Folder 2013 --> December

I would like to do this using C# code. If not, i can go with PowerShell script too.

Kindly share your thoughts on it. It going to be an high priority issue for me.

Regards,

Comment: Please share with us what you have already accomplished. It should be pretty straightforward task using MoveTo method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.moveto.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial worked for me as i wanted the same.

http://like2know.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-move-sharepoint-list-items-to.html

Answer (score 0):

> following code may help you :)

SPListItemCollection collListItems = oDocumentLibrary.Items;

```
                        foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)
                        {
                            if (oListItem.File != null)
                            {
                                if ((DateTime.Now - oListItem.File.TimeCreated).TotalDays <= 100)
                                {
                                    temp_date_Created = oListItem.File.TimeCreated;
                                    if (temp_date_Created >= date_Created)
                                    {
                                        date_Created=temp_date_Created;
                                         file_url = oListItem.Url;

                                    }

                                }


                            }


                        }
```

Comment: Above logic finds files created within 100 days from current date